# Pass makefile automatic variable value to bash function called from make

Tags: makefile

Say I have the following function defined in my `.bashrc`:

```
foo (){
    touch $1
    }
```

I want to call this function in a makefile like so:

```
%.png : %.tex
    bash -i -c foo $<
```

But this complains about a missing operand. (The error is "`touch: missing file operand`", so it is calling `touch`...). I've seen some solutions to similar issues, but they aren't applicable since I need the automatic variable `$<` (or rather, its value) to be passed as an argument to the shell script.

I know I could work around this problem (copy the function wholesale into the makefile, for example) but I'm curious to see how I could solve my problem within the makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is *probably* because you don't have enough quoting.  The shell `-c` option takes its script as a *single argument*.

Consider:

```
$ bash -c echo hi
<prints nothing>
```

Versus:

```
$ bash -c 'echo hi'
hi
```

Comment: I can't quote the argument to bash, because I need make to interpret `$<`. But I see how that's part of the problem.

Comment: No you don't.  Make doesn't care about quotes.  Make doesn't even know _how_ to interpret a shell script to handle quoting properly.  Make always expands every `$` in the recipe, unless it's escaped via `$$`  The only variables you have to worry about enclosing in quote are _shell_ variables, not make variables; `$<` is a make variable.  Try it.  It will work.

Comment: Oh right sure, if I actually removed the other bug from my makefile it would work perfectly! (my testing script was `touch`ing the dependency file, not the required output, so it looked like nothing was happening. (it should be `foo $@`)